# Why do some writers on EM theory call the displacement $\vec D$ a field? It's a hybrid quantity - a field ($\vec E$) plus a charge displacement vector

Tags: electrostatics, terminology, gauss-law, dielectric, displacement

Gauss' equation for free space balances the number of charges in a volume with the amount of $\vec E$ field flux through the surface of the volume. When material is included in the volume, a new term appears in Gauss's equation - it describes the displacement of bound charges through the surface. Because the equation now contains 2 flux terms (the dot products of a $\vec E$ with $\hat n$ and the polarization vector $\vec P$ with $\hat n$), it is a mathematical convenience to combine the 2 terms under one integral. This leads to naming their sum as  $\vec D$, but  $\vec D$ is not a physical quantity -- it is the sum of 2 physical quantities.

Comment: Neither $\mathbf{P}$ nor $\mathbf{D}$ are physical quantities in the sense of being measurable and rigorously defined. But both are useful, and both are fields in the sense of being vector values over all of space.

Comment: This is a historical relic. Maxwell called it the displacement field because he literally thought of it as the displacement of some component of the ether. Now we don't think that way anymore, since it's not very useful. But $\mathbf{D}$ itself is still a formally useful quantity for solving problems, despite the lack of a simple physical interpretation for it, so we still use it.

Comment: D is the effective medium electric field.

Comment: Since when has the sum of two physical quantities not been a valid physical quantity itself (dimensional considerations excluded)?

Answer (score 1):

A continuous quantity, where we can assign a strength to every point is called a field. Hence, we formally write $D(\vec x, t)$.